# What happened to mDNS or Bonjour? Do I need it anymore?

Tags: windows-10, mdns, bonjour

Bonjour used to be the way to get peer to peer name resolution, and might still be, but I'm confused about a few things.  The [latest page](https://support.apple.com/kb/dl999?locale=en_US) from Apple gives you v2, and it was released on 2010, approx ***14 years*** ago from today.  For so-called modern tech, this doesn't seem right.  Even if you use [their search](https://support.apple.com/kb/index?page=search&src=support_serp&locale=en_GB&currentPage=1&product=&doctype=&includeArchived=false&query=Download%20Bonjour), you still get pointed to that page.  I found a [Chocolatey page](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/bonjour#files) with v3, but no date for context, nor much other information, so I'm not sure what to do with this.

Looking on the internet, there are plenty of SuperUser questions asking about Bonjour, but they are all older questions.  Looking on Wikipedia, it seems the technology might have been rebranded to mDNSResponder.  Apple has a [Github](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/mDNSResponder) with mDNSResponder, but their [releases page](https://opensource.apple.com/releases/) only gives you source code, not anything that you can install.

I also saw that Windows has built-in mDNSResponder now, but based on the questions here on SuperUser, I don't think it works.  I also found that [BSD](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/how-to-install-and-configure-mdnsresponder.70713/) does not have a native client.

However, I'm not clear on what happened, nor what software is needed, if at all.  I am asking from a Windows 10 perspective.

1. Did Bonjour get rebranded?
2. Do you need 3rd party software for mDNS resolution anymore?
3. Who is the authoritative source for such software?
4. Where do you get the software?
5. Where does Avahi come into play?

These questions are on-topic for the following reasons:

2. There are 685 questions about Bonjour.
3. There are 684 questions regarding mDNS.
4. There are many questions about how to install Bonjour on various versions of windows.  This is a similar question, but not a duplicate, and more articulate.
5. There are similar, but not duplicate, questions about how to configure or fix Bonjour on Windows.
6. There are similar, but not duplicate, questions about how to configure or fix mDNS on Windows.
7. There are many questions about how to install Bonjour on MacOS.  This is a similar question, but not a duplicate.
8. There are many questions about how to install Bonjour on Linux.  This is a similar question, but not a duplicate.

Comment: Your question only has a close vote. You have 5 questions and 8 statements saying the reason your question is within scope, had focused on the question, you would have avoided that close vote.

Comment: Nah man, I have not had a question survive more than a few hours in like 8 years on any SE site, that's what my defensiveness is about.

Comment: Every question you have asked in the last 3 years is opened and answered. I have provided feedback. If you have questions closed, do they contain unnecessary information like justification, to not close the question and contain multiple questions?

Comment: The only thing you NEED to do to make this question a good fit for this site is to post a single question. That is a pretty clear part of the rules on this site, and the reasoning why is laid out in the Help section. But you NEED to do that, because right now you are earning the close votes by asking multiple questions.

Comment: I find this a very relevant question, no reason to close it!

Comment: @KjeldFlarup you must be new here.  The StackExchange network hates questions.  If I had instead posted 8 questions related to Bonjour at the same time, all 8 would have been closed as duplicates (leaving 0 questions), assuming they weren't flagged as spam.

Answer (score 3):

> The latest page from Apple gives you v2, and it was released on 2010, approx 14 years ago from today. For so-called modern tech, this doesn't seem right

It was called "modern" in 2000 when it replaced AppleTalk, and the description was accurate at that point. (The main alternative, NetBIOS, was already showing its age – this was roughly the same time when Microsoft had also switched from NetBIOS to a purely IP-and-DNS-based system for their Active Directory.)

The v3 of Bonjour that you found is an official version; it's what Apple distributes with iTunes (they never offered it as a separate download, but it does work fine stand-alone). But around that time, Apple was already reducing their efforts on Windows software; not just Bonjour but the rest as well.

> Looking on Wikipedia, it seems the technology might have been rebranded to mDNSResponder

"Bonjour" is the marketing name, "mDNSResponder" is the name of the actual program (like how Microsoft Office Word is "winword.exe").

> I also saw that Windows has built-in mDNSResponder now

It doesn't. The "mDNSResponder" process that you might see on some Windows systems is still Apple's Bonjour, which is (or at least used to be) automatically installed as part of iTunes.

Windows 10 (as of release 10.16xx or thereabouts) **does** have a built-in mDNS and DNS-SD implementation, but it is not called "mDNSResponder". Rather, it's part of the same "Dnscache" service that also handles regular DNS.

(Keep in mind that mDNS is used not only for hostname lookup, but also for service discovery. Earlier Windows 10 versions had mDNS support for *service discovery* – namely printer discovery – but not yet for hostname lookup, which came later.)

> but based on the questions here on SuperUser, I don't think it works.

The 'hostname lookup' part certainly works. I'm using it.

Whether it is *enabled* by default depends on which Windows 10 version you're looking at. I don't have any sources handy but I think it took Microsoft until 10.20xx to actually make mDNS-based name resolution available out of the box; before that, it only worked after it was manually enabled. Nowadays, however, [see Microsoft's official statement on mDNS.](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/networking-blog/aligning-on-mdns-ramping-down-netbios-name-resolution-and-llmnr/ba-p/3290816)

Service discovery (DNS-SD) is a different question. Windows had that even before it had hostname resolution; but when it comes to developing programs that use it, the built-in client provides a complex DNS-SD API that is completely different from Bonjour's, and for a while, the API it did provide was restricted to UWP apps only (whereas most developers still write "traditional" Win32 apps). It certainly works – Windows can find printers via mDNS/DNS-SD, though not yet SMB servers – but so far there's very little usage of it.

> I also found that BSD does not have a native client.

It depends on *which* BSD (there hasn't been a single OS called "BSD" for decades – the various BSD-derivatives are all separate from each other), but Avahi runs on most BSDs and is available e.g. in OpenBSD 'ports' as net/avahi (even though, as far as I know, OpenBSD doesn't even offer the extension points that would allow it to handle name resolution – though it can still handle DNS-SD).

> Did Bonjour get rebranded?

The protocol implemented by Bonjour has always been known as "Multicast DNS" and "DNS-SD", broadly under the "Zeroconf" branding at least since early 2000s.

Nowadays, "Bonjour" specifically refers to the original *implementation* of mDNS/DNS-SD by Apple (i.e. the "mDNSResponder" service).

> Who is the authoritative source for such software?

Nobody. mDNS and DNS-SD are not proprietary protocols and do not have any specific authoritative implementer, much like there is no authoritative source for an HTTP client.

The authoritative source for the *protocol* is currently IETF, with Apple's own RFC 6762 being the specification for mDNS and RFC 6763 for DNS-SD.

(It's also a simple enough protocol with few edge cases that "must handle it the way Apple does, even if spec says otherwise" is not a significant factor when implementing.)

Currently mDNSResponder is still probably the only implementation of Apple's further work on SRP (an extension of mDNS/DNS-SD more suitable for "modern" networks of 2020s), but the actual protocol is still developed through an IETF WG.

> Where does Avahi come into play?

Avahi is another implementation of mDNS and DNS-SD, started in 2004 and targeted towards Linux and other Unix-like systems; these days it's the "default" implementation on most Linux distributions. (It's independent from Bonjour, although for a while it used to be an API-compatible replacement.)

(It is also not the *only* implementation of mDNS on Linux; systemd-resolved has plans to supersede it, and I believe Chrome/Android has its own mDNS software as well.)

Comment: You beat me to a very similar answer, so I'll dump mine. Additional notes: Apple considers their Bonjour to be open source under Apache 2.0. They keep a repository for developers linked from https://developer.apple.com/licensing-trademarks/bonjour/#bonjourwin though there is much newer material on their GitHub page - https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/mDNSResponder/tags [I'm not a dev, so I've no real clue what it all is;)